# Create Extension Method for classes with same structure and different number of columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, extension-methods

I have a Entity Framework data mode that I insert to it some stored procedure and for every of those SPs I create a complex type.For example my sp 1 has this complex type:

```
sp1_result
{
      string c1;
      string c2;
      string c3;
      string c4;
}
```

and for example sp 2 has this complex type:

```
sp2_result
{
      string c1;
      string c2;
}
```

and so on.I want to convert List of this complex results to `DataTable` but they have different number of columns but their types are equal. How I can write an `Extension Method` for this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which make use of reflection and create `DataTable` form the `List` collection of the object...

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts IList object to Datatable
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"> name of the class - List Type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="pList"> IList object</param>
        /// <returns>Datatable</returns>
        public static DataTable ConvertTo<T>(IList<T> pList)
        {
            DataTable table = CreateTable<T>();
            Type entityType = typeof(T);
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(entityType);

            foreach (T item in pList)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();

                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item);
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.but what is `CreateTable<T>();`? I want to build my DataTable from my class columns

Comment: should `(IList<T> pList) ` convert to `(this IList<T> pList) ` ?

Comment: @Rozhin - hey method takes list of object i.e collection and generate DataTable form it